# XMLSerializer throws exception

Tags: java, xml, json, serialization

I have a small piece of code to parse XML to JSON. It works fine until I introduce the XMLSerializer to get the JSON.

```
public static String convertXMLFileToString(String fileName) 
{
  try{ 
    XMLSerializer xmlSer = new XMLSerializer();
    DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(); 
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName)); 
    org.w3c.dom.Document doc = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(inputStream); 
    StringWriter stw = new StringWriter(); 
    Transformer serializer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(); 
    serializer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(stw));
    String st = stw.toString();
    JSON json = xmlSer.read(st);
    return stw.toString(); 
  } catch (Exception e) { 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
  } 
    return null; 
  }
```

The call:

```
convertXMLFileToString("/home/tom/workspace/xmlToJson/files/input/sample.xml");
```

Im using JSON-lib-2.4 and the following import `import net.sf.json.xml.XMLSerializer;`
and I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/exception/NestableRuntimeException
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at convert.xmlToJson.convertXMLFileToString(xmlToJson.java:27)
at convert.xmlToJson.main(xmlToJson.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.exception.NestableRuntimeException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
... 14 more
```

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: It's an issue with JSON-lib but the .read() function I need is not implemented in the other libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON-lib has dependencies to other libraries, see http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/.

- jakarta commons-lang 2.5
- jakarta commons-beanutils 1.8.0
- jakarta commons-collections 3.2.1
- jakarta commons-logging 1.1.1
- ezmorph 1.0.6

Can't say whether you need all of them, but your exception clearly indicates that it's missing commons-lang ( http://commons.apache.org/lang/ ). Make sure to use version 2.x, *not* the newer 3.x.